# Flutter. Create a List<String> of the firestore documents and collections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch a list of documents (documentID) from Firestore and add it to a List. I have seen some options but since I am a little new in this area, perhaps the obvious is becoming difficult for me. And I don't know exactly where in the code those lines should go, for example in an initState.

This is one of the options that I have chosen, but it only generates instances and not the name of the documents as such.

```
final QuerySnapshot result =
      await Firestore.instance.collection('submits').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

List<String> myListString = []; // My list I want to create.
myListString.add(documents);    // The way I try to add the doc list to my String list.
```

Example the data base. I want to get a list of the document ID to a List-String-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtxTw.png)

And if possible, you could tell me if there is an analogous way to apply it to obtain a List  but in the case of two or more collections.

Comment: You will have to write code to iterate the `documents` list and produce the final list based on whatever you have in those documents.  Since we can't see what's in those documents or know what sort of strings you're trying to collect, we can't be of much help.  If you're still stuck, I suggest editing the question to be more clear about the result you expect, and the contents of your documents from this query.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, I have updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want is a list of the document ids, right?

If so, this should work:

```
final QuerySnapshot result =
      await Firestore.instance.collection('submits').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

List<String> myListString = []; // My list I want to create.

documents.forEach((snapshot) {
   myListString.add(snapshot.documentID)
});
```

Comment: That's right, I want to create a list of the IDs of the documents. I will try the proposed solution, I thank you very much.

Comment: No prob, let me know how it goes!
Please consider marking it as the correct answer if it worked

Comment: That's right, I just tried your solution and it worked for me. One more question, is there a way to execute the code automatically, for now I am executing it through a button. But I would like that when I access the screen where I will use the list of documents, they appear automatically, should I use an InitState?

Comment: Effectively put the function into an InitState and it has worked perfectly. Thank you!!!